# CSV Regex skipping first comma

Tags: regex, dart

I am using regex for CSV processing where data can be in Quotes, or no quotes. But if there is just a comma at the starting column, it skips it.

Here is the regex I am using:
`(?:,"|^")(""|[\w\W]*?)(?=",|"$)|(?:,(?!")|^(?!"))([^,]*?|)(?=$|,)`

Now the example data I am using is:
`,"data",moredata,"Data"`
Which should have 4 matches ["","data","moredata","Data"], but it always skips the first comma. It is fine if there is quotes on the first column, or it is not blank, but if it is empty with no quotes, it ignores it.

Here is a sample code I am using for testing purposes, it is written in Dart:

```dart
void main() {

  String delimiter = ",";
  String rawRow = ',,"data",moredata,"Data"';
RegExp exp = new RegExp(r'(?:'+ delimiter + r'"|^")(^,|""|[\w\W]*?)(?="'+ delimiter + r'|"$)|(?:'+ delimiter + '(?!")|^(?!"))([^'+ delimiter + r']*?)(?=$|'+ delimiter + r')');


Iterable<Match> matches = exp.allMatches(rawRow.replaceAll("\n","").replaceAll("\r","").trim());
List<String> row = new List();
matches.forEach((Match m) {
  //This checks to see which match group it found the item in.
  String cellValue;
  if (m.group(2) != null) {
    //Data found without speech marks
    cellValue = m.group(2);
  } else if (m.group(1) != null) {
    //Data found with speech marks (so it removes escaped quotes)
    cellValue = m.group(1).replaceAll('""', '"');
  }  else {
    //Anything left
    cellValue = m.group(0).replaceAll('""', '"');
  }
  row.add(cellValue);
});
  print(row.toString());

}
```

Comment: Which tool/language are you using?

Comment: Dart, I have edited my qutestion to include some example code of it in Dart, I assume it less relevant which language it is, as it is just regex. Here is an example of it in a regex tester website. https://regex101.com/r/ctwDtS/1

Comment: language is relevant. In java for example, there is no such method. Instead, you *split* the string by matching the *separators*, rather than matching the target strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigating your expression

```
(,"|^")
(""|[\w\W]*?)
(?=",|"$)
|
(,(?!")|^(?!"))
([^,]*?|)
(?=$|,)
```

`(,"|^")(""|[\w\W]*?)(?=",|"$)` This part is to match quoted strings, that seem to work for you

Going through this part `(,(?!")|^(?!"))([^,]*?|)(?=$|,)`
`(,(?!")|^(?!"))` start with comma not followed by " OR start of line not followed by "
`([^,]*?|)` Start of line or comma zero or more non greedy and |, why |
`(?=$|,)` end of line or , .

In CSV this `,,,3,4,5` line should give 6 matches but the above only gets 5

You could add `(^(?=,))` at the begining of second part, the part that matches non quoted sections.
Second group with match of start and also added non capture to groups
`(?:^(?=,))|(?:,(?!")|^(?!"))(?:[^,]*?)(?=$|,)`

Complete: `(?:,"|^")(?:""|[\w\W]*?)(?=",|"$)|(?:^(?=,))|(?:,(?!")|^(?!"))(?:[^,]*?)(?=$|,)`

Here is another that might work
`(?:(?:"(?:[^"]|"")*"|(?<=,)[^,]*(?=,))|^[^,]+|^(?=,)|[^,]+$|(?<=,)$)`
How that works i described here: [Build CSV parser using regex](http://goorep.se:1001/changelog/report/rSelect/PAGE_result.htm?alias=guest&set=&query=Book%20pages&$$TArticleBook1.ArticleBookK=7105&$$TArticle2.ArticleK=9420&$$TArticle2.ArticleK=9425&$$TArticle2.ArticleK=9426&$$TArticle2.ArticleK=9427&link=[[%22B510C1D203054C4D98B0215AAE499B5Ezoom%22,%22TArticleBook1%22,7105]])

Comment: Your fix to my regex, didn't seem to work, it didn't pick up the first item still. Thank you for your regex though it is a different way to do it, and it does pick up the first item if blank. I will look more into that one.

Comment: My bad. Switch the order comparing quoted string and non quoted string and it should work.  
`(?:^(?=,))|(?:,(?!")|^(?!"))(?:[^,]*?)(?=$|,)|(?:,"|^")(?:""|[\w\W]*?)(?=",|"$)`